# JS. Курсы валют

Tags: javascript, парсер

Господа, помогите новичку в первых шагах. Хочу научится отображать курсы валют/нефти/крипты и прочего.

Для начала интересует сам вывод курса с какого-либо ресурса. Без всяких там графиков, динамик и т.д.

То есть, нужен пример кода. Вот, допустим, USD, а рядом выводится его курс, например с сайта ЦБ (https://www.cbr.ru/currency_base/daily/).

Как не пытаюсь гуглить, какие-то примеры попадаются, но дико специфические. Мне, как новичку, тяжело вычленить из них то, что мне нужно.

И поскольку уж очень хочу во всём этом разобраться, буду ещё рад различным материалам на данную тему. Желательно что-то такое поэтапное - от простых примеров к более сложным.

Заранее всем спасибо.

Comment: А при чем тут javascript? Вам на Node.js нужен парсер?

Comment: указанный вами поставщик информации вроде как имеет [api](https://www.cbr.ru/Reception/Faq/Search/?q=api), после того как ознакомитесь   с ним. делаете ajax запрос, обрабатываете ответ, выводите на страницу

Answer (score 4):

Лучше работать с REST API. Парсить HTML не комильфо...
Пример запроса:

```js
fetch('https://api.exmo.com/v1/ticker/').then(async(result) => {
  // результат запроса
  if (result.status === 200 && result.ok) {
    // превращение в JSON
    return result.json()
  }
}).then((JSON_DATA) => {
  // вывод данных
  console.log('Список получен: ', JSON_DATA);
  // действия с данными...
}).catch((error) => {
  // обработка ошибок
  console.error('Ошибка получения списка: ', error);
})
```

Для очень новичков: Чтобы заработало достаточно вставить к консоль браузера